# How to solve this non-linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This came from a regression:

$$\text{Diameter} = 0.0531052 + 0.0443237 \cdot \exp (-0.0103633 \cdot \text{'Time elapsed'})$$

if diameter is $-0.052$

What will be time elapsed, can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. In the future please include your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$D_i = -0.0531052 + 0.0443237\exp(-0.0103633\Delta t)$$

Solve for $\Delta t$ to obtain

$$\Delta t = -\dfrac{1}{0.0103633}\ln\dfrac{D_i+0.0531052}{0.0443237}$$